# Ruby array assignment produces unexpected result

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
a = [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']]
b = [['-'] * 3] * 3 # => [["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"]]
a == b #=> true
```

Seems correct.

```
a[0][0] = 'X'
a # => [["X", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"]]

b[0][0] = 'X'
b # => [["X", "-", "-"], ["X", "-", "-"], ["X", "-", "-"]]

a == b # => false
```

What? Why does `b[0][0] = 'X'` change values in three places?

I also found it doesn't work this way:

```
b = [%w[- - -]] * 3 # => [["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"]]
b[0][0] = 'X'
b # => [["X", "-", "-"], ["X", "-", "-"], ["X", "-", "-"]]
```

Comment: Of course Ruby is correct, unless you have hit a bug. And there is no Ruby bug related to what you have shown here.

Comment: What do you mean by "(doesn't) work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it has to be done this way:

```
irb(main):001:0> b = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) { '-' } }
=> [["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"]]
irb(main):002:0> b[0][0] = 'X'
=> "X"
irb(main):003:0> b
=> [["X", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"]]
```

Comment: Right. `[['-'] * 3] * 3` creates an array, then creates two references to that same array object. But `Array.new(3) { ... }` calls its block 3 times, and each time it creates and yields a new object.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
[object]*3
```

will create an array with 3 references to the same object so changing one of them changes all of them like this:

```
a = [[1]]*3 #=> [[1], [1], [1]]
a[0][0] = 2 #=> [[2], [2], [2]]
```

If you wish to create an array of length 3 with 3 different objects, do this:

```
a = 3.times.map {[1]} #=> [[1], [1], [1]]
a[0][0] = 2           #=> [[2], [1], [1]]
```

Comment: When mysteries like this emerge, check `a.map(&:object_id)` to see what objects are in the array. If the numbers are all the same, they're all the same object.

Answer (score 1):

The first initialization you created 3 arrays nested in 1.

```
a = [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']]
#   [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']] 
#         ARRAY a          ARRAY b          ARRAY c
```

The second initialization you created 1 array, and then pointed the same array 3 times.

```
b = [['-'] * 3] * 3
#   [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']] 
#         ARRAY x          ARRAY x          ARRAY x
```

Thinking in this way if you change b[0][0] is going to alter only one array, however you can have the impression that is changing more arrays because it's being referenced many times.

You can check it by yourself printing the addresses of them.

```
puts a[0].object_id # 47369457807480
puts a[1].object_id # 47369457807320
puts a[2].object_id # 47369457807200

puts b[0].object_id # 47369457807070
puts b[1].object_id # 47369457807070
puts b[2].object_id # 47369457807070
```